# CodeIgniter updating data using radio button for each row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, updates

i want to update data using radio button for each row of my data.

Example:

My table

> id | name | age | number | account | note | place | radio

[image]

after i click the radio button (Mencurigakan/Tidak Mencurigakan), the radio will be updated. I tried using this code and i cannot read my **id** column and i only can update one row

> Controller:

```
public function updateradio($id) {
    $data=$this->welcome_model;
    $data->radio=$this->input->post("radio$id");
    $data->update_bb($id);          
}
```

> Model:

```
public function update_bb($id) {
   $id = /*i need something here*/
   $data = array('radio' => $this->input->post("radio$id"));            
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $this->db->update('info', $data);        
}
```

> View:

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->id . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->name . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->age . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->number . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . "Rp " . $row->account . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->note . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row->place . '</td>';
    ?>                        
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/updateradio" method="post">    
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="3"/>
                Mencurigakan
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="2"/>
                Tidak Mencurigakan
            </label>
        </div>                          
    </td>
    <?php
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-group">Update</button>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your info table column names and a row from it?

Comment: The screen shoot is my info table, there are two row in it @MahbubulIslam

Comment: Please make single form for your problem afterwards you can try.